# server cookie = null

Tags: java, blackberry

I am doing authentication and receiving a null cookie.  I want to store this cookie but sever is not returning me a cookie. But the response code is 200 ok.

```
httpConn.setRequestProperty(
    "Authorization", 
    "Basic " + Base64OutputStream.encodeAsString(
                   login.getBytes(), 0, login.getBytes().length, false, false)); 

String tmpCookie = httpConn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
```

This is my code.

```
String login = username + ":" + password;

String base = "http://mysever/login";
HttpConnection httpConn = null; 
httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(base); 
// Setup HTTP Request to POST                
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpsConnection.POST);                
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
    "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/x-javascript,*/*;q=0.5 ");
//Add the authorized header.
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", 
    "Basic " + Base64OutputStream.encodeAsString(
                   login.getBytes(), 0, login.getBytes().length, false, false));

message = httpConn.getResponseMessage();
status = httpConn.getResponseCode();           
tmpCookie = httpConn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

EventLogger.logEvent(guid, status);

if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) 
{
    String tmpCookie = httpConn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
    authForm.append("\nConnected");
    authForm.append("\n\nLogin Response:" + message + 
                        "\nHTTP response code:" + status + "\nCookie: " 
                        + tmpCookie); 
    //getNewZipFile();
}                   
else if(status !=HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
    throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + status); 
}
httpConn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually made a connection? Your code shows you setting a request property and then immediately trying to find a header value, with no indication that the request has actually been sent.

If you *are* doing so (in which case fuller code would be welcome) you should use [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) or something similar to find out what the network traffic actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

How request Authorization header connected with response Cookie?
I suppose that it is in no way.

May be server doesn't return any cookies? Or may be "set-cookie" is case sensitive, and you must use "Set-Cookie" instead.

Comment: I am using Set-Cookie. And it is still showing as null. I know that I am suppose to get a cookie from sever but I am just not getting it.